# GKE Workload Identity service account for all namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-iam

I'm following the [guide](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity) to setup GCP's Workload Identity and have it working for a service account configured against the default Kubernetes namespace as below:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
  --role roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser \
  --member "serviceAccount:[PROJECT_ID].svc.id.goog[default/[KSA_NAME]]" \
  [GSA_NAME]@[PROJECT_ID].iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to create the binding for all k8s namespaces; something like below, where I've replaced the default namespace with `*`:

```
--member "serviceAccount:[PROJECT_ID].svc.id.goog[*/[KSA_NAME]]"
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set all namespaces to a Kubernetes Service Account(KSA).
Maybe you would have to get each namespace and doing the binding for each namespace, an automation script could help in the process to do it n times (1 time for each namespace).

You can get only namespaces column name using the following kubectl command:

```
kubectl get ns --all-namespaces --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name"
```

Getting something like this:

```
default
kube-public
kube-system
```

Which can be used to iterate them using a binding automation script.